# Removing input label when typing

Tags: javascript, css

I have an input field that I cannot use a placeholder for, instead I must use a label and place it as it was a placeholder, so right in the field. How can I hide the label when you start typing into the field, and make the label reappear hen all letters are removed from the field - so just like the placeholder ould behave?

My html:

```
  <label class="PR_label" for="PR">My label</label>
  <input type="hidden" name="PR" value="" id="TR">
```

EDIT: I realised this is not possible since my input field is hidden and you cannot enter/type anything since there is no fied to begin with.

Comment: Did you tried something? On change check length of content and either hide or show label

Comment: Give the label an id. Use the 'change' event on the input to check every time if there's text. Then show/hide the label accordingly.

Comment: _"How can I hide the label when you start typing into the field"_ - with _that_ code? Not at all, because hidden input fields can't be typed into to begin with :-)

Comment: Could you not just use placeholder?,

Comment: it's an accessibility nightmare to use an input field without a label and a placeholder, if you need to style the placeholder use the ::placeholder pseudo selector.

Comment: The problem is that the input is hidden because another field is loaded on top with iframe. Unfortunately the js of the iframe is loading too late, so now there is no placeholder until the iframe is loaded, and I would like to give one to the hidden field...

Comment: Your input is first and foremost hidden, because you put `type="hidden"`. Whether or not different content is displayed on top of this, is pretty irrelevant - the user would not see a form field with `type="hidden"` either way, whether there was something on top of it, or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the label inside the textbox using `position: absolute;` and then hide the label when the user types, using an event listener:

```js
var textbox = document.getElementById("input_box")
var label = document.getElementById("label")


textbox.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
    label.style.display = "none"
    }, false);
```

```css
#input_box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0px;
}
#label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <input value="" id="input_box">
        <label id="label">Lorem ipsum</label>
        <script src="code.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use your label as placeholder in your input field you can use CSS position.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-control {
  width:50%;
  padding: 0.625rem;
  position: relative;
}
label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.7rem;
  right: 1.625rem;
  color: blue;
}
input[type="text"] {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-control">  
  <label class="PR_label" for="PR">test</label>
  <input type="text" name="PR" value="a" id="TR">  
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make use of a placeholder inside your input and also don't forget to add alternative keys for accessibility checks.

**WITH PLACEHOLDER**

```html
<input id="TR" class="text" type="text" name="PR" value="" placeholder="PR" alt="PR">
```

**WITHOUT PLACEHOLDER**

Using jQuery

```js
$(".input").each(function () {
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    $(this)
        .focus(function (event) {
            if (this.value == inputVal) {
                this.value = "";
            }
        })
        .blur(function (event) {
            if (this.value == "") {
                this.value = inputVal;
            }
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Example Value" class="input">
```